# grid show no data but there is request thu direct why

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

i have this storge:
http://www.pasteall.org/30062/javascript
as well this grid: 
http://www.pasteall.org/30063/javascript
now see this resulte from 
http://www.pasteall.org/pic/28491 
its been called but no data been draw why?????

i am lost ...

note: 
i am usings MVC of EXTJS please let me know what missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your missing the [`store`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.panel.Table-cfg-store) config and its required...

I suppose the `source` config in your code should be replaced with `store`.

Comment: woot didnt saw at:) 3 hours from my life gone ^^

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your view code: `soruce` instead of `source`. And I think it should be `store` not `source`